# How can I remove HTTP headers with .htaccess in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-headers, remove

I have a website that is sending out "cache-control" and "pragma" HTTP headers for PHP requests.
I'm not doing that in the code, so I'm assuming it's some kind of Apache configuration, as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047902/what-could-be-adding-pragmano-cache-to-my-response-headers-apache-php) (you don't really need to go there for this question's context)

I don't have anything in my .htaccess files, so it's gotta be in Apache's configuration itself, but I can't access that, this is a shared hosting, I only have FTP access to my website's directory.

Is there any way that I can add directives to *my* .htaccess files that will remove the headers added by the global configuration, or otherwise override the directive so that they're not added in the first place?

Thank you very much
Daniel

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just replied to my own question...

```
Header unset Pragma
Header unset Last-Modified
Header unset Cache-Control
```

Comment: with apache 2.4 i had to do `Header always unset pragma`